# Conditional text in variable in ansible

Tags: if-statement, variables, ansible

H I want to build a warning message with ansible that is stored in a variable:

I have {{total}} and {{wanted}} and I want to store that in a {{outcome}} variable :

I need something like :

```
if ({{total}} < {{wanted}}): {{outcome}}= "you need to much"
else if ({{total}} = {{wanted}}): {{outcome}}= "Could work out"
else: {{outcome}}= "Ok"
```

How can I get this to work?

Thanks for any ideas... this is driving me crazy....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task below does the job

```
- set_fact:
    outcome: |
      {% if total|int < wanted|int %}
      You need to much
      {% elif total|int == wanted|int %}
      Could work out
      {% else %}
      Ok
      {% endif %}
```